# Access Response from HTTParty Request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parsing, httparty

I'm obtaining a token from an external API via HTTParty.

My call looks like this:

```
token_request = HTTParty.post(@url, body: token_payload.to_json, headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
```

I receive back the following JSON:

```
{"token":"TBpdV20Fsdbycgmib2B8ZhasVnRb","expiration_utctimestamp":"23123202226","error_code":0,"error_message":null}
```

I now want to pass the token value into my next request.

How do I get the "TBpdV20Fsdbycgmib2B8ZhasVnRb" bit into a variable? My guess is this, but doesn't work:

```
token = token_request[:token]
```

Thanks

Comment: How about `token_request['token']`? As you see in the output, the key is a string, not a symbol.

Comment: If I change :token to 'token' it just returns the string: 'token' in the terminal. I'd like the value, not the key, though.

Comment: Ok, then what does the `token_request` variable contains exactly?

Comment: [Exact output in terminal](https://imgur.com/a/4l7L6) @MarekLipka

Answer (score 0):

HTTParty contains helper method that returns parsed JSON as a hash (if server responds with appropriate header). So you can access token via:

```
token = token_request.parsed_response['token']
```

Another way in this particular case (server does not return `application/json` header):

```
token = JSON.parse(token_request.to_s)['token']
```

Comment: Thanks Nate. I tried both. In first example I get the same: a string 'token' but not the value. In second example I get the following: [Error message](https://imgur.com/a/KQ8cD)

Comment: Be aware that it's a HTTParty POST I'm doing. Not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: Show me please console output of `puts token_request.body`. Screenshot is tough to read & reproduce. It seems like server responds with invalid JSON

Comment: This is what I get in the terminal: "{\"token\":\"TBpcbV20FFSwbycgmib2B8Zh2MhnwGVnRb\",\"expiration_utctimestamp\":\"1511302226\",\"error_code\":0,\"error_message\":null}"

Comment: And what is for `puts token_request.parsed_response`?

Comment: The following: {"token":"TBpcbV20FFSwbycgmib2B8Zh2MhnwGVnRb","expiration_utctimestamp":"1511302226","error_code":0,"error_message":null}

Comment: and I assume `token_request.parsed_response.class` is String, not Hash?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159481/discussion-between-nattfodd-and-andy).